# Datafetcher for nested types in graphql

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I am using graphql and graphql-java for a simple API that fetches projects and its assignee

```
schema {
  query: Query
}

type Query {
   projects: [Project]
   users: [User]
}

type Project {
   id: ID!
   name: String
   assignee : User
   status: String

}

type User {
   id: ID!
   name: String
}
```

I already have following resolvers:

```
private RuntimeWiring buildRunTimeWiring() {
return RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()
    .type("Query", typeWiring -> typeWiring
    .dataFetcher("projects", allProjectsDataFetcher)
    .dataFetcher("users", allUserDataFetcher)
    ).build();
}
```

How should I write my resolvers so that when I query

```
projects {
  id
  name
  assignee
}
```

it should return projects and its assignees. Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your resolver code (which looks good to me) and hope its resolves Project and associated assignee inside that object, I see problem in your graphQL schema (if you are expecting list of users). It should look like ...

```
type Project {
   id: ID!
   name: String
   assignee : [User]
   status: String
}
```

Make sure you return Object which should look like

```
{id:1, name:"someName",status:"Active", assignee :[{id:003, name:"A"}, {id:004, name:"B"}]}
```

Comment: My question is - do i need to create this object structure myself within the "allProjectsDataFetcher" resolver? 

Is there a way I can specify connection and graphql resolve it itself ?

Comment: No. GraphQL is schema specification, it does not create object structure automatically. You can create a model and keep properties same as in graphQL type definition and send this model (after assigning values )  as response from resolver then only graphQL will map properties.